# Debugger Visualizer - Magnifying Glass not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've started to write a debugger visualizer library, however it is not working as expected.

A magnifying glass should be there when I hover over a variable I created a visualizer for, but it is not. Obviously, visual studio doesn't tell me what is wrong.

The following code resides in the visualizer library (class library project targeting 4.0).

Dialog Debugger:

```
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(
typeof(ColorRGBA8Visualizer),
typeof(Serializer<ColorRGBA8>),
Target = typeof(ColorRGBA8),
Description = "ColorRGBA8 Visualizer")]

public class ColorRGBA8Visualizer
    : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
{
    public static void TestShowVisualizer(object objectToVisualize)
    {
        var visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(objectToVisualize,
            typeof(ColorRGBA8Visualizer),
            typeof(Serializer<ColorRGBA8>));
        visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
    }

    protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
    {
        var color = Serializer<ColorRGBA8>.GetValue(objectProvider);
        using (var form = new Form())
        {
            form.Text = "Color Visualizer";
            form.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, color.R, color.G, color.B);
            form.Size = new Size(100, 10);
            windowService.ShowDialog(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Serializer because I need it for more complex objects anyways:

```
public class Serializer<T>
    : VisualizerObjectSource
{
    public static T GetValue(IVisualizerObjectProvider provider)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
        var transport = (MemoryStream) provider.GetObject();
        var value = serializer.ReadObject(transport);

        return (T) value;
    }

    public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
    {
        var value = (T) target;
        var transport = new MemoryStream();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(transport, value);
        transport.Position = 0;

        base.GetData(transport, outgoingData);
    }
}
```

My Test Console Application:

```
internal class Program
{
    #region Static Methods

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = new ColorRGBA8{R=255};
        ColorRGBA8Visualizer.TestShowVisualizer(value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The dialog shows up alright, but the whole goddamn point is to have the button to show the dialog appear when hovering over the variable "value" in this point.

Yes, my visualizer library is output' to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers" via building the library: All required references are copied as well.

[Here's what it looks like in my debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T68Q.png)

[That's what I expected it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdGvW.png)

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

*edit*

**This is the solution, as suggested by [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar). For some unknown reason, visual studio refuses to work with generic serializers, even when they are specified as a closed type, such as Serializer.**

```
public class ColorRGBA8Serializer
    : VisualizerObjectSource
{
    public static ColorRGBA8 GetValue(IVisualizerObjectProvider provider)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ColorRGBA8));
        var transport = (MemoryStream)provider.GetObject();
        var value = serializer.ReadObject(transport);

        return (ColorRGBA8)value;
    }

    public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
    {
        var value = (ColorRGBA8)target;
        var transport = new MemoryStream();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ColorRGBA8));
        serializer.WriteObject(transport, value);
        transport.Position = 0;

        base.GetData(transport, outgoingData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be your use of a generic type for the second argument of `DebuggerVisualizerAttribute`.  The visualizer system is limited with respect to generics and for some reason it seems to be rejecting a generic in this position.  I was able to get the form to show up using your code with changing only the visualizer source argument to be non-generic

Note: I don't have a good explanation as to why the behavior is what it is.  It logically doesn't make sense but experimentally it bears out

Comment: Thank you so much. This problem has driven me mad. It really is confusing why this doesn't work out of the box with my code.

Comment: @Simon yes it's quite surprising it's the problem. I just made a lucky guess that the generics could be the issue